# How to select a particular button?

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm creating a web app for storing notes of the users. For each note I'm creating a `div` using `createElement` in JS and adding a `button` (to delete the note) and some text into it.
If a person have 10 notes then I'm creating 10 `div`s using a `for` loop.
My question is how to select buttons so that when user wants to delete that particulat note I can do that.

```js
let messArray = ['some text', 'some other text']
let i = 0;
let notePrev = document.getElementById('notePrev');

for (let mess of messArray) {
    // creating elements
    const box = document.createElement('div');
    box.id = i;
    const btndiv = document.createElement('div');
    const btn1 = document.createElement('button');

    // adding class to elements
    box.classList.add('prevClass');
    btndiv.classList.add('btndiv');
    btn1.classList.add('btn');
    btn1.innerText = 'Delete'

    // appending element to body
    btndiv.append(btn1);
    box.append(mess);
    box.append(btndiv);
    notePrev.append(box);
    i++;
}
```

```html
<div id="notePrev"></div>
```

Comment: You can assign unique `id` to your button

Answer (score 1):

You can add an eventlistener to the button and in the eventlisteners' code access the parents elements for the deletion. See this example code:

```js
let messArray = ['some text', 'some other text']
let i = 0;
let notePrev = document.getElementById('notePrev');

for (let mess of messArray) {
    // creating elements
    const box = document.createElement('div');
    box.id = i;
    const btndiv = document.createElement('div');
    const btn1 = document.createElement('button');

    // adding class to elements
    box.classList.add('prevClass');
    btndiv.classList.add('btndiv');
    btn1.classList.add('btn');
    btn1.innerText = 'Delete'
    btn1.addEventListener('click',function() {
        this.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    });

    // appending element to body
    btndiv.append(btn1);
    box.append(mess);
    box.append(btndiv);
    notePrev.append(box);
    
    i++;
}
```

```html
<div id="notePrev"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
   if(event.target.classList.contains('btn')){
      event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
   }
})
```

For detailed information, read about event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply manipulate dom like below example
Dom elements gives you `this` value on it's events as itself so you can access it into onclick event

```js
function remove(e){
  e.parentElement.remove()
}
function convertNotes(){
  let notes = document.querySelector("#notesInput").value.split("\n")
  document.querySelector("#notes").innerHTML = notes.map(note=>`<li>${note} <button onclick="remove(this)">Delete</button></li>`).join("")
}
```

```html
<div>Notes:</div>
<textarea placeholder="split your notes with new line" id="notesInput"></textarea>
<button onclick="convertNotes()">Convert Notes</button>
<ul id="notes">
</ul>
```